# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException - paint()

Tags: java, swing, paint, mouselistener, mousemotionlistener

i'm testing another simple program for drawing a line. First problem is the error.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GUI$2.paint(GUI.java:57)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
```

This is the code for line 57
`g.drawLine(pointStart.x, pointStart.y, pointEnd.x, pointEnd.y);`

```
panel = new JPanel(){
        Point pointStart = null;
        Point pointEnd = null;
        int x = 1;
        {   
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                    pointStart = e.getPoint();
                }
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
                    pointEnd = e.getPoint();
                }
            });
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter(){
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
                    pointEnd = e.getPoint();
                }
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
                    pointEnd = e.getPoint();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            super.paint(g);
            g.setColor(a);
            g.drawLine(pointStart.x, pointStart.y, pointEnd.x, pointEnd.y);
        }
    };
```

If i can ask, how do i save the lines that has been drawn? Thanks

Comment: You're using the field `pointStart` in your draw method with `pointStart.x` etc. but you're not assigning any value to them until the mouse is clicked, so before you click the mouse you're gonna get a lot of NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (note that this is the `paintComponent()` method, not `paint()`):

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(a);
    if(pointStart!=null && pointEnd!=null){
        g.drawLine(pointStart.x, pointStart.y, pointEnd.x, pointEnd.y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your real code exactly like this? Because when your program reaches to the line 57 there wasn't any initialization for the `pointStart` and `pointEnd` members. So there is a very obvious reason for `NullPointerException` to happen since `paint()` or `paintComponent()` or `paintComponents()` methods are called so many time during the initial rendering, iconify/deiconify or resizing or ... of a panel. So this calls are very supposed to happen before user create any `mouseClick` or `mouseDrag` events to initialize those points.

May be it is better for you to have class which `extends` **JPanel** and has a constructor to get `pointStart` and `pointEnd` as arguments of the constructor to avoid this `NullPointerException`.

If you cannot determine in the time of creation of this panel you must either check the nullity of `pointStart` and `pointEnd` or initialize both of them with (0,0).

After your panel is added to the parent container, if the parent's `paintComponents` method is called (can happen for many number of reasons and so many times), your `paint` or `paintComponents` methods is called relatively.

Good Luck.

Comment: Your welcome. Typically when an answer helps, you may vote it up or mark it as the answer.